# Referencing to the EntityFramework.dll cause an run-time error in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ef-code-first, runtime-error

**[Updated]**

I have 2 projects in my solution. the first one is my DAL project(Class Library), and the second is a Windows Project(UI), my DAL Project referenced to EF 4.3.1 and worked normally, 
Recently **I referenced my DAL project** to `EF6` , using Package Manager Console, by `Update-Package EntityFramework` command, in VS2010, after applying the recommended  changes in [EF official site](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6), now the **app.config of my DAL project** include these lines:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>
```

and

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=erptest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa_l4;password=12212121;application name = LEVEL4" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

But when I run my project, when control comes to below line

```
var context = new MyDbContext();
```

I got this error:

```
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.Odbc'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file
```

Does anyone knows, where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your DAL project is a class library, it will use the config of the application which consumes it.

Try adding the Entity Framework Nuget package to your UI project. It will add the required settings to the config.

**Update**

This issue can also be caused by a profiling tools like Glimpse or EF Profiler. If you are using either, try disabling them to see if it will fix the problem.

Comment: Are you using any kind of profiler like EF Profiler or Glimpse? It seems that they can lead to issues with EF -
http://stackoverflow.com/q/15857349/2868772

Comment: Thanks alot snacky, the problem solved, I used EF Profiler and when disabled it, the problem solved. plz update your post. do you know how can i use EF profiler also?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I've updated the answer as requested. It looks like a bug so you should probably contact Hibernating rhinos support - http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/contact

Comment: I had this one after installing EF6, removing Glimpse fixed it, thanks snacky

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a configuration issue...do you have the below entry in your `web.config` file?

```
<entity-framework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entity-framework>
```

Your specific config entries will likely need some additional/different entries/properties but you can read here for more info on EF6 configurations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx